# Are Ultimate-evolutions horrifically immoral?

Tags: ben-10

So the explanation for *Ben 10*'s ultimate forms in *Ben 10: Ultimate Alien*, is that a computer simulation is ran for a million years of a selected alien form in a horrific battlefield and Ultimatrix records any evolution made by the alien in question. Does that mean every time Ben uses this ability he's putting a living sentient (admittedly simulated) creature through a million years of torture just for a quick combat boost?

Is there any canon talking about this? Or any signs that the aliens aren't sentient while this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### We don't exactly know if the aliens are sentient but the Ultimatrix is the work of an inmoral being

While the Ultimatrix began as a work of Azmuth (a scientist with peaceful intent and good intentions) it was stolen by [Albedo](http://ben10.wikia.com/wiki/Albedo) who completed it and added the evolution feature.

Albedo is vengeful and ambitious, and exhibits sociopathic behaviors disregarding other people's lives.

Quoting Ben10 wiki:

> The successor of the Omnitrix with some of the same features as the Omnitrix. Azmuth wasn't finished making it when ***it was stolen, completed, and modified by Albedo*** in The Final Battle: Part 1, ***who added an evolution feature that evolves aliens into their Ultimate form***.

Answer (score 4):

Usually no. The aliens in ben's watch are not *usually* sentient.

However in the epsiode "The Ultimate Sacrifice" it is revealed that due to a glitch in the ultimatrix several ultimate aliens achieved sentience. They lived inside the architecture of the watch growing to resent ben as he used their forms. Eventually they asserted their dominance and tried to kill ben so they could be freed from the watch. When the watch is taken to Asmuth he fixes the bug and makes sure no other forms become sentient. However due to not a little bit of Deus Ex Machina and handwaving the ultimate forms that did achieve sentience are freed and brought to a planet where they can live in peace.

So we know that the ultimatrix can definately create real thinking creatures with their own desires and emotions. Now you might think thats where it ends but actually when Ultimate Humongusaur was asked about his childhood he said his mother tried to eat him when he was born. Now whether he actually lived this or it was some Blade Runner-esque artificial memory is unclear but the show definately seems to agree whatever it is is highly unethical.

If you'd like to read more about the episode you can go here:

http://ben10.wikia.com/wiki/The_Ultimate_Sacrifice

Comment: Good answer! Are there any more canonical sources than the wiki?

Comment: The Wikipedia page listing all the episodes of Ben 10: Ultimate Alien does mention the plot synopsis. Unfortunately I don't know of any official sources for the plots of episodes.

Its Season 3, Episode 39 according to wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ben_10:_Ultimate_Alien_episodes